# Excel error: Method 'Refresh' of object 'WorkbookConnection' failed. Then it crashes

Tags: excel, vba

I am using 2013 32-bit Excel.

I am attempting to change the name of the text file within the data connection, in code (see below). It was originally set up manually within the spreadsheet by going recording a macro going:

> `Data` tab → `From Text` → `Get External Data group`

There are several connections in this spreadsheet, all set up manually, and all need to be updated in code. They are all connections of the same type: **text**.

When I execute the code below, Excel returns an error on the **`Refresh`** statement:

> ```
> "Method 'Refresh' of object 'WorkbookConnection' failed"
> ```

Then I step again, and this time it successfully executes the `Refresh` statement, in the sense that it doesn't return an error. But when I then press `F5` to continue, Excel crashes.

```
Dim wC As WorkbookConnection
Dim rG As Range
Dim rSummary As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sChangeValue As String
Dim sWorksheetName As String
Dim sDataTableName As String
Dim sConnection As String
Dim lo As ListObject


For Each wC In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    If wC.Type = xlConnectionTypeTEXT Then
        'I say "For Each", but in practice there is only one range per sheet
        For Each rG In wC.Ranges
            Set rSummary = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("d_QueryTable").Range
            sChangeValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wC.Name, rSummary, 7, False)
            If sChangeValue = "Y" Then
                sWorksheetName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wC.Name, rSummary, 2, False)
                sDataTableName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wC.Name, rSummary, 3, False)
                sConnection = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wC.Name, rSummary, 10, False)
                With wC
                    .TextConnection.Connection = sConnection
                    .Refresh
                End With
                'sh(sWorksheetName).ListObjects(sDataTableName).TableObject.Refresh
            End If
        Next rG
    End If
Next wC
```

The `wC.TextConnection.Connection` field takes the value

```
"TEXT;Y:\Investigations\run_49.csv"
```

The value I am changing it to, stored in `sConnection`, for testing purposes, is identical. But why then do I get the *Refresh* error? And why then does Excel crash?

All help appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you **Step** to the next line instead of pushing `F5`?  The answer to that will help identify which line is *actually* causing the error.

Comment: @ashleedawg see the comment below your post below

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get the error because the `.TextConnection.Connection` is before the `.Refresh` and SQL Server does not like it at all.

In general, the `.Connection` in SQL Server is really a sentitive information (extremely sensitive, in a way that there is nothing more sensitive in the whole SQL Server) and SQL Server avoids to set it up simply like this. Try this to see the hash, in which SQL Server keeps the connection string:

```
Sub TestME()

    Dim wC As WorkbookConnection
    Dim rG As Range
    Dim rSummary As Range

    For Each wC In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        For Each rG In wC.Ranges
            Set rSummary = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:H100")
            With wC
                Debug.Print .OLEDBConnection.Connection
                .Refresh
            End With
        Next rG
    Next wC
End Sub
```

It should be around 1000+ random signs, printed on the immediate window.

Comment: When I run this, and I get to the debug.print line, it returns the error "Application-defined or object-defined error". Possibly because there are no OLEDB connections within the spreadsheet? They're all text connections.  If I change the OLEDBConnection keyword to TextConnection, I get the string that was specified in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, almost all VBA crashes are caused by memory problems, **usually objects being somehow handled incorrectly**.

I would bet it is because of this line:

```
Set rSummary = Sheets("Summary").ListObjects("d_QueryTable").Range
```

You are "re-`Set`ing" that object numerous times, with each iteration of the first two loops.

Since it probably only needs to be set ***once***, move that line to before the first `For` statement.

Comment: That line needs to be witin the first for loop, as it will be reset for every connection, wC, in this case. I have it within the second for loop, which is unneccessary, in this instance. I moved it to be after the first for loop, but I still get the same error on Refresh. Then I step past the Refresh statement, and it doesn't fall over. However, when I then pressed F5, Excel didn't crash. So that's progress.

Comment: Best practice when resetting" objects is to set them to `Nothing` when you're finished with them, before re-using them.  In this case, use `Set rSummary = Nothing` , perhaps just before your `With` statement. I'm telling ya, I'd almost bet money that the crashes are related to mis-handling of an **object**, and that's the only one I see [in the loop anyways].   (but I'm kinda blind sometimes!) :-)

Comment: Basically make sure any object that's created/opened is set to `nothing` and/or `close`d, as applicable...also, another "best practice": put `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module (if it's not already there) to help identify potential issues with variables/objects/etc

Comment: Well, the progress i'd made in my first comment above, was a false dawn. When I attempted to save the spreadsheet after F5 had finished running, it crashed. I've tidied up the objects in the module as per your suggestions, but it hasn't made any difference. Firstly, Excel still returns the same error message, and secondly, it crashes when I press F5. The real key here is the error message as that's what occurs first.

Comment: Oh! Another suggestion:  **Reboot!**  I *always* forget that [if my theory about this being a memory issue is correct] Excel tends to leave crap in the memory like "ghost processes".  So, try rebooting, and if you lost the changes you made, make them again before running your procedure again.  (My brain *also * has memory issues, I'm still quite confident that the problem has something to do with an object.)

Comment: ...since it crashes while saving, and Excel didn't save your changed properly, maybe copy all the changed code to Notepad as a backup before you run it, and then step through the code (No F5 until you make it all the way through at least once!)  ...And you're sure that the only code it's running is in the procedure you shared, correct?

Comment: rebooting makes no difference. yes, the only code that's running is in the procedure I shared. When I make changes, I save before running, as it always crashes.